# Is it possible in MySql to associate inserted data to a specific user?

Tags: mysql

I just was wondering if is it possible to associate an user to the data inserted in a table.

For example:

I have a table `Customers` with columns `customerID`, `name` and `address`. Is there any method in MySql to know what user has inserted each row in the table or must I add a column `userID` in the table Customer to add the user in my SQL Insert statement?.

If I have only one table, it is not a proble to add the `userID` column. But when i have multiple tables, maybe it becomes a messy task.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find out the `user_id` caused the insert then *NO*, there is no other way than you storing it explicitly likewise you already have thought of.

If there is multiple tables for which you want to store the same information; then you can probably have a separate table where you can have the `user_id` column and can use a `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` to insert the user id in this table.

Answer (score 1):

No, no such functionality is provided by MySQL. You'll have to add a column for user_id in your table(s) and insert the user id yourself.